# Use conditional expression in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have journal - list of actions that can be two types: call and message.
I need to take 5 numbers that has most of received calls and messages with LINQ. Same for numbers that sent these actions.

```
class Action
{
    public static int Id { get; }
    public int Sender { get; }
    public int Receiver { get; }
    public OperationTypes Type { get; }
    public string MessageText { get; }

    public Action(int sender, int receiver, OperationTypes type, string message = "")
    {
        Id++;
        Sender = sender;
        Receiver = receiver;
        Type = type;

        MessageText = (type == OperationTypes.Message) ? message : string.Empty;
    }
```

The problem is about thing that i need to count call as 1 and message as 0.5 so and count this sum for result.

```
var accounts = _journal
            .Select(x => new {x.Receiver, x.Type})
            .GroupBy(x => x.Receiver)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count())
            .Take(5);
```

Don`t get how to do it properly with LINQ and count message as 0.5 * call.

Comment: I don't think you can't assign a value to a read-only static property (`Id++;`) from an instance constructor...

Comment: match better to include your target result.

Comment: It is easy to do. Use the same conditional as assigns `MessageText`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [Aluan Haddad's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915893/aluan-haddad) hint above, try adding a computed `Value` property:

```
class Action
{
    ...

    public double Value => Type == OperationTypes.Message ? 0.5 : 1.0;
}
```

Then use `Value` in your anonymous type, and sum it instead of counting in your `OrderByDescending` call:

```
        var accounts = _journal
            .Select(x => new { x.Receiver, x.Value })
            .GroupBy(x => x.Receiver)
            .OrderByDescending(x => x.Sum(action => action.Value))
            .Take(5);
```

Comment: Fantastic! Glad to help.